# Allow adding PDF certificates to Developer Story

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, stack-overflow-jobs, developer-story

Add a feature to have the possibility to add some PDF certificates from massive open online courses to developer story.

It would be nice to have an alternative to the mainstream recruitment sites.

Currently it is impossible to do so.

Comment: Note: feature requests generally get better reception if you include a justification for the feature you are requesting ([see the tag wiki for `feature-request` for more info](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/feature-request/info)). Right now, this request reads like a command.

Comment: Thanks, @MikeMcCaughan. Will think of good justification it in the evening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately, adding PDF files (or any sort of attachments) to your developer story is not something we have on our current roadmap, so we won't be implementing this feature anytime soon.

Alternatively, you can provide URLs to your PDF files, if they are publicly available, on many story item types (job, education, blogs & videos, features & apps). I realized we didn't allow URLs on certifications though, so I'm adding support to that right now. Should be up with our next prod build.

Comment: It looks nice, thank you for your contribution!
Will it be possible to have it with a thumbnail?